# Bamboo plan is not starting with Bitucket commit

Tags: bitbucket, bamboo

I have bamboo set up with the testing branch of my Bitbucket repository, and I have set the build plan to trigger when new commits are pushed. Also linked bamboo from Bitbucket as a sevice and link.
[Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uY6gf.png) [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIaVO.png)

The problem is that when I push code to testing branch, it won't trigger the build plan. Is there any other thing to do?